# An introductory tutorial on UnQL (the newest CouchDB, Sqlite unifier language)?

Tags: sqlite, nosql, couchdb, unql

The CouchDB and Sqlite founders , in collaboration with microsoft research recently announced a new querying language UnQL which promises to combine the two worlds of SQL and NoSQL After googling around for some time , I have given up on finding an introductory tutorial. Can somebody help with this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a concept at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the only resources about UnQL so far are several diagrams and syntax notes at the [spec home](http://www.unqlspec.org/). I think that there is still a lot of work on the details of the spec and it's implementation into the specific databases would take even more time, however it looks like a good move and starting point to standardize/unite querying mechanisms among NoSQL solutions.

Comment: At CouchConf there was a demo that the creator of Sqlite said would be available for download. Although incomplete and buggy, it is a way to get your feet wet.

Comment: The test suite when you clone the fossil repository is interesting and shows what I/O you can have with the sample executable.